# Invariant violation nothing was returnded from render

Tags: react-native

renderAvail(user, sectionId, rowId, highlightRow){

```
    return(
      <ImageBackground  source={require('../../../asset/available_card_medium.png')} style={styles.containerA}>
      if(user.type == 'Wear'){
        return(
      <Image
        source={require('../../../icon.png')}
        resizeMode = 'cover' style={styles.thumbImage}>)
      }
      <View style={styles.body}>
        <Text style={styles.message1}>{user.desc}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.message1}>+{user.points} <Image source={require('../../../icon_large.png')} resizeMode ='contain' style ={{height:50,width:60}}/></Text>
      </View>
      <ImageButton
      appearance={{
        normal: require("../../../asset/btn.png"),
        highlight: require("../../../asset/btn2.png")}}
      onPress={ this.onPressButton }/>
      </ImageBackground>
  );
}
```

{
        id: 0,
        type: 'Survey',
        desc: 'Keep Your Apple Watch on for 8 Hours Today',
        title: 'Test1',
        date: '09/06/2018',
     },
     {
        id: 1,
        type: 'Wear',
       desc: 'Keep Your Apple Watch on for 8 Hours Today',
        title: 'Test1',
        date: '09/06/2018',
     },
     {
        id: 2,
        type: 'meal',
        desc: 'Keep Your Apple Watch on for 8 Hours Today',
        title: 'Test1',
        date: '09/06/2018',
     },
     {
        id: 3,
        type: 'Survey',
       desc: 'Keep Your Apple Watch on for 8 Hours Today',
        title: 'Test1',
        date: '09/06/2018',
     },
     {
        id: 4,
        type: 'Wear',
        desc: 'Keep Your Apple Watch on for 8 Hours Today',
        title: 'Test1',
        date: '09/06/2018',
     }
  ];

Comment: when i do this it works 
      renderAvail(user, sectionId, rowId, highlightRow){
        if(user.type == 'Wear'){
        return(
          <ImageBackground  source={require('../../../asset/_medium.png')} style={styles.containerA}>

Comment: but it only works with if i want to check if the usertype is wear and the rest it just return by else like that 
)}else {
        return(
          <ImageBackground  source={require('../../../asset/large3.png')} style={styles.containerA}>
          </ImageBackground>

      )}

Comment: what i want is to if based on the user type it will return the rows with the correct image and text.

Comment: Two words: [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Comment: Please edit your question, adding the details from your comments, and try to structure the it a little more clearly.  Maybe move the description to the top.

Comment: sorry i am a bit new to this so pardon if i have posted in a wrong way

Answer (score 0):

You cant return use return directly inside a return block because it will be already returned if condition meets. instead of above code, you can use this.

```
return (<ImageBackground source={require('../../../asset/available_card_medium.png')} style={styles.containerA}>
    {user.type == 'Wear' && <Image
        source={require('../../../icon.png')}
        resizeMode='cover' style={styles.thumbImage}>)
      }
      <View style={styles.body}>
            <Text style={styles.message1}>{user.desc}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.message1}>+{user.points} <Image source={require('../../../icon_large.png')} resizeMode='contain' style={{ height: 50, width: 60 }} /></Text>
        </View>
        <ImageButton
            appearance={{
                normal: require("../../../asset/btn.png"),
                highlight: require("../../../asset/btn2.png")
            }}
            onPress={this.onPressButton} />

      </ImageBackground>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Going through your code i can understand that you are new to react native.

As @Ranvir Gorai answered previously, you can not use if statement inside a render(). please spare some time and go through JSX elements.

Assuming you are calling a function renderAvail() from render of a class.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
```

// add other elements which are used.

```
} from 'react-native';
export default class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user:'some data',
            sectionId:'some data',
            rowId: 'some data',
            highlightRow: 'some data',
        }
    }
    // add the data to state using this.setState({key,value}); 


    renderAvail() {
        return (
            <ImageBackground source={require('../../../asset/available_card_medium.png')} style={styles.containerA}>
                {user.type == 'Wear' && <Image
                source={require('../../../icon.png')}
                resizeMode='cover' style={styles.thumbImage}>)
                }
              <View style={styles.body}>
                    <Text style={styles.message1}>{user.desc}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.message1}>+{user.points} <Image source={require('../../../icon_large.png')} resizeMode='contain' style={{ height: 50, width: 60 }} /></Text>
                </View>
                <ImageButton
                    appearance={{
                        normal: require("../../../asset/btn.png"),
                        highlight: require("../../../asset/btn2.png")
                    }}
                    onPress={this.onPressButton} />

              </ImageBackground>
        );
    }


    render() {
        return (
            {this.renderAvail(this.state.user, this.state.sectionId, this.state.rowId, this.state.highlightRow)}
        );
    }
}
```